# Syntax error to combine left join and select

Tags: sql, left-join

I'm getting a syntax error at Left Join. So in trying to combine the two, i used the left join and the brackets. I'm not sure where the problem is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.order_id
FROM fact.outbound AS a
ORDER BY Rand()
LIMIT 5
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      outbound.marketplace_name,
      outbound.product_type,
      outbound.mpid,
      outbound.order_id,
      outbound.sku,
      pbdh.mpid,
      pbdh.product_type,
      pbdh.validated_exp_reach,
      pbdh.ultimate_sales_rank_de,
      pbdh.ultimate_sales_rank_fr,
      (
        pbdh.very_good_stock_count + good_stock_count + new_Stock_count
      ) as total_stock
    FROM
      fact.outbound AS outbound
      LEFT JOIN reporting_layer.pricing_bi_data_historisation AS pbdh ON outbound.mpid = pbdh.mpid
      AND trunc(outbound.ordered_date) = trunc(pbdh.importdate)
    WHERE
      outbound.ordered_date > '2022-01-01'
      AND pbdh.importdate > '2022-01-01'
    LIMIT
      5
  ) AS b ON a.orderid = b.order_id
```

Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around: 'LEFT JOIN ( SELECT outbound.marketplace_name, outbound.product_t' at line 9

What could be the reason?

Comment: The reason is that you did not read the docs.    A  `LIMIT` should not appear before a LEFT JOIN.  For MySQL see: [select](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html), for PostgreSQL see: [select](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html)

Comment: P.S.  Why did you not read the text that is attached to the tag `sql` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the first limit logic into a separate subquery, and then join the two subqueries:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT a.order_id
FROM
(
    SELECT order_id
    FROM fact.outbound
    ORDER BY Rand()
    LIMIT 5
) a
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        outbound.marketplace_name,
        outbound.product_type,
        outbound.mpid,
        outbound.order_id,
        outbound.sku,
        pbdh.mpid,
        pbdh.product_type,
        pbdh.validated_exp_reach,
        pbdh.ultimate_sales_rank_de,
        pbdh.ultimate_sales_rank_fr,
        (pbdh.very_good_stock_count +
         good_stock_count + new_Stock_count) AS total_stock
    FROM fact.outbound AS outbound
    LEFT JOIN reporting_layer.pricing_bi_data_historisation AS pbdh
        ON outbound.mpid = pbdh.mpid AND
           TRUNC(outbound.ordered_date) = TRUNC(pbdh.importdate)
   WHERE outbound.ordered_date > '2022-01-01' AND
         pbdh.importdate > '2022-01-01'
   -- there should be an ORDER BY clause here...
   LIMIT 5
) AS b
    ON a.orderid = b.order_id;
```

Note that the select clause of the `b` subquery can be reduced to just the `order_id`, as no values from this subquery are actually selected in the end.

Comment: You can even skip the LEFT JOIN, since no b columns are selected. (And SELECT DISTINCT makes sure any duplicates are eliminated.)

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the `LEFT JOIN`, since no b columns are selected. (And `SELECT DISTINCT` makes sure any duplicates are eliminated.)

```
SELECT DISTINCT order_id
FROM fact.outbound
ORDER BY Rand()
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: If I were to select the b columns and display them, how would i do it?

Comment: Your query may not strictly be correct **if** the subquery after the left join might not return every order available in the A table, which is likely does not.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, it's a LEFT JOIN, i.e. table b matches doesn't matter except that duplicates can be created. But SELECT DISTINCT will remove any duplicates.

Comment: Can you please give me an example how i can change it to return the subquery?